# Mongoose, how to do a find() with two or more parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have such example:

> http://host.com/entries?users[0]=steve&users[1]=edward

This query should give me only users with such names

I have do such code

```
exports.find = (req, res, next) ->
  e = req.query.entries

  if hosts
    e = ({$or: [{entry}]} for entry in e)

    Collection.find {active: true}
    $and: e
    .exec (err, results) ->
      console.log results
      res.json results
```

But it returns me empty list
How I can use mongoose in correct way?

Comment: what you get in variable e ?

Comment: @niteshsingh [ { '$or': [ [Object] ] }, { '$or': [ [Object] ] } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **$in** operator to search from array.

Example: you have an array of names like `var names = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz' ]`

Resolution:

**Callback**

```
var searchQuery = {name: {$in: names}};
UserModel.find(searchQuery, function(err, foundUsers){
  if(err){
    //do something with err
  } else {
    //do something with foundUsers
  }
});
```

**Promise**

```
var searchQuery = {name: {$in: names}};
UserModel
  .find(searchQuery)
  .exec()
  .then(function(foundUsers){
    //do something with foundUsers
  })
  .onReject(function(err){
    //do something with err
  });
```

As for parameters in your query, you may add them as many as you want just like adding new keys into JSON object:

```
var searchQuery = {
  'foo': 'bar',
  'baz': 'qux'
};
```